# LINQ Any an array to predicate an array whether it consists of the text of the first array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I would like to check whether first array match with second array items, the second array have texts that I want to match with the first array.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> FirstArrayToLookup = new List<string>();
    List<string> SecondArrayToLookup = new List<string>();
    List<string> ThirdArrayToLookup = new List<string>();
    
    FirstArrayToLookup.Add("FirstArray1");
    FirstArrayToLookup.Add("FirstArray2");
    
    SecondArrayToLookup.Add("SecondArray1");
    
    ThirdArrayToLookup.Add("ThirdArray1");
    ThirdArrayToLookup.Add("ThirdArray2");
    ThirdArrayToLookup.Add("ThirdArray3");
    
    string[] FirstStringContains = { "Array1", "Array2" };
    string[] SecondStringContains = { "Array1" };
    string[] ThirdStringContains = { "Array1", "Array2", "Array3" };
    
    if (FirstArrayToLookup.All(x => FirstStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
        Console.WriteLine("First Array to Lookup");
    
    if (SecondArrayToLookup.All(x => SecondStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
        Console.WriteLine("Second Array to Lookup");
    
    if (ThirdArrayToLookup.All(x => ThirdStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
        Console.WriteLine("Third Array to Lookup");
}
```

The above code will only return `Second Array to Lookup`, where what I want to achieve is if the `FirstArrayToLookup` variable match with the `FirstStringContains` variable, then it should return `First Array to Lookup`, same goes with the other conditions. However only the `Second Array to Lookup` is returned, but not `First Array to Lookup` and `Third Array to Lookup`. The `FirstArrayToLookup` have to be match with `FirstStringContains`, same goes with others.

.Net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rhTMuz

Anyone knows on how to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Because it overrides the existing value at last `JobPositionText = JobPosition.OtherPosition.ToString();`. Try comment this line and see the result.

Comment: Hi @YongShun, sorry, the question was my mistake, I have updated my question, could you please kindly help to see the updated questions as well? basically the second array consists of text that I want to match contains against the first array.. the first text in the first array could be any with `Junior Developer` behind the text or `Junior Specialist`, and the second array just to categorize. Means if first array have `Web Junior Developer` and `Web Junior Specialist`, it will match the `JuniorJobPosition` variable. Thank you

Comment: Hint for a good question: Always revise the question before posting. Edit question only for providing details/clarification. While I go through the previous edit of this question, the latest version's question is quite different (topic) from the original question. And so the answer posted is not aimed/answer to the question. You should post as new question instead of keep editing the same question

Comment: Hi @YongShun, okay will remember that in the future. I have posted a new question as well regarding what I want to achieve (basically it should print `First Array to Lookup` as well as `Third Array to Lookup` as it does match the conditions. Would you please mind to help me regarding this? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697058/match-the-condition-of-the-first-array-to-be-contains-with-second-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st version**

While your requirement:

> when ArrayToLookup has all text of Web Junior Developer and Software Junior Developer, it should return JuniorPosition
>
> when the ArrayToLookup has all text of Web Senior Developer and Software Senior Developer

You need to use `.All()`. With `.Any()` it returns true when any condition is fulfilled.

While [`.All()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-6.0) return true when all the conditions are fulfilled.

```cs
if (ArrayToLookup.All(x => JuniorJobPosition.Contains(x)))
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.JuniorPosition.ToString();

else if (ArrayToLookup.All(x => SeniorJobPosition.Contains(x)))
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.SeniorPosition.ToString();

else
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.OtherPosition.ToString();
```

OR

```cs
if (ArrayToLookup.All(x => JuniorJobPosition.Contains(x)))
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.JuniorPosition.ToString();

if (ArrayToLookup.All(x => SeniorJobPosition.Contains(x)))
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.SeniorPosition.ToString();

if (JobPositionText == JobPosition.None.ToString())
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.OtherPosition.ToString();
```

[Sample Program (1st version)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wCbYBH)

---

**2nd version**

You need to check whether the text (in the second array) consists of text in `ArrayLookup`. Any of it fulfills the result will return true.

```cs
if (ArrayToLookup.Any(x => JuniorJobPosition.Any(y => x.Contains(y))))
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.JuniorPosition.ToString();
        
if (ArrayToLookup.Any(x => SeniorJobPosition.Any(y => x.Contains(y))))
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.SeniorPosition.ToString();
```

[Sample Program (2nd version)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UOyUIK)

Comment: Hi @YongShun, sorry, the question was my mistake, I have updated my question, could you please kindly help to see the updated questions as well? basically the second array consists of text that I want to match contains against the first array.. the first text in the first array could be any with `Junior Developer` behind the text or `Junior Specialist`, and the second array just to categorize. Means if first array have `Web Junior Developer` and `Web Junior Specialist`, it will match the `JuniorJobPosition` variable. Thank you

Comment: Hi @YongShun, thank you for your earlier answer, may I ask for your help again to help me regarding the updated question above? Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @YongShun, I have tried it with if else if else, however it is not print `First Array to Lookup` as well as `Third Array to Lookup`, I have posted a new question regarding this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697058/match-the-condition-of-the-first-array-to-be-contains-with-second-array , would you please mind to help me regarding this? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

refactor your Conditions to

```
  if (ArrayToLookup.Any(x => JuniorJobPosition.Contains(x)))
  {
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.JuniorPosition.ToString();
  }
  else if (ArrayToLookup.Any(x => SeniorJobPosition.Contains(x)))
  {
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.SeniorPosition.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.OtherPosition.ToString();
  }
```

alternatively you could check

```
  if (ArrayToLookup.Intersect (JuniorJobPosition). Any())
  {
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.JuniorPosition.ToString();
  }
  else if (ArrayToLookup.Intersect (SeniorJobPosition). Any())
  {
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.SeniorPosition.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
    JobPositionText = JobPosition.OtherPosition.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Hi @dba, sorry, the question was my mistake, I have updated my question, could you please kindly help to see the updated questions as well? basically the second array consists of text that I want to match contains against the first array.. the first text in the first array could be any with `Junior Developer` behind the text or `Junior Specialist`, and the second array just to categorize. Means if first array have `Web Junior Developer` and `Web Junior Specialist`, it will match the `JuniorJobPosition` variable. Thank you

Comment: what if the ArrayLookup contains "junior" AND "senior"?

Comment: Hi @dba, thank you for your earlier answer, may I ask for your help again to help me regarding the updated question above? Thank you very much