# Match the condition of the first array to be contains with second array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I would like to check whether first array match with second array items, the second array have texts that I want to match with the first array.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> FirstArrayToLookup = new List<string>();
    List<string> SecondArrayToLookup = new List<string>();
    List<string> ThirdArrayToLookup = new List<string>();
    
    FirstArrayToLookup.Add("FirstArray1");
    FirstArrayToLookup.Add("FirstArray2");
    
    SecondArrayToLookup.Add("SecondArray1");
    
    ThirdArrayToLookup.Add("ThirdArray1");
    ThirdArrayToLookup.Add("ThirdArray2");
    ThirdArrayToLookup.Add("ThirdArray3");
    
    string[] FirstStringContains = { "Array1", "Array2" };
    string[] SecondStringContains = { "Array1" };
    string[] ThirdStringContains = { "Array1", "Array2", "Array3" };
    
    if (FirstArrayToLookup.All(x => FirstStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
        Console.WriteLine("First Array to Lookup");
    
    if (SecondArrayToLookup.All(x => SecondStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
        Console.WriteLine("Second Array to Lookup");
    
    if (ThirdArrayToLookup.All(x => ThirdStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
        Console.WriteLine("Third Array to Lookup");
}
```

The above code will only return `Second Array to Lookup`, where what I want to achieve is if the `FirstArrayToLookup` variable match with the `FirstStringContains` variable ***(which it does as because `FirstArrayToLookup` does have items which has the word of `Array1` and `Array2`, same goes with their check condition `FirstStringContains`)***, then it should return `First Array to Lookup`, same goes with the others. However only the `Second Array to Lookup` is returned, but not `First Array to Lookup` and `Third Array to Lookup`. The `FirstArrayToLookup` have to be match with `FirstStringContains`, same goes with others.

Basically, from user point of view, as because the `FirstArrayToLookup` has `Array1` and `Array2`, and it check against the `FirstStringContains` that has `Array1` and `Array2` also which fulfills the condition, it should print `First Array to Lookup`, same goes with others as it is check against their respective `ArrayToLookup` with `StringContains` variable

.Net fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rhTMuz

Anyone knows on how to solve this?

**UPDATE**:

I have tried to use as according to the following question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691739/linq-any-an-array-to-predicate-an-array-whether-it-consists-of-the-text-of-the-f?noredirect=1#71691936) , which uses the if else conditions, however it does not fulfills what I want, which is it should print `First Array to Lookup`, `Second Array to Lookup` and `Third Array to Lookup`, as because `FirstArrayToLookup` does contains `Array1` and `Array2` items inside them and their check against does contains `Array1` and `Array2` items as well inside them, same goes with `SecondArrayToLookup` with their check `SecondStringContains`, and `ThirdArrayToLookup` with their check `ThirdStringContains`. Currently it only returns `Second Array to Lookup` which only fulfills the condition of `SecondArrayToLookup` with their check `SecondStringContains`

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5DZpfL

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5TMFhl) meets your requirement.

Comment: Hi @YongShun, thank you very much, it does meet my requirement, however if I do remove the `ThirdArray3` in `ThirdArrayToLookup`, it also prints `Third Array to Lookup` which is it should not happen as because it only needs to meet `ThirdStringContains` while `ThirdArrayToLookup` can be any words inside them, but it will have the words of `Array1`, `Array2` and `Array3`. [Demo of the latest requirement](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4cDNT) . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at one of the statements that doesn't evaluate to true:

```
if (FirstArrayToLookup.All(x => FirstStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))))
    Console.WriteLine("First Array to Lookup");
```

Specifically this secondary `.All()` query, using the first value contained in `FirstArrayToLookup` (`"FirstArray1"`):

```
FirstStringContains.All(y => x.Contains(y))
```

This is saying "for the values contained in `FirstStringContains` (`"Array1"`, `"Array2"`) does `"FirstArray1"` contain ALL of these values?" So, does the literal value of `"FirstArray1"` contain both `"Array1"` AND `"Array2"`? It only contains `"Array1"`, thus the evaluation of false for that statement.

The second statement is returning true because there is only one value to check against one value.

Comment: Hi @rbrettj, the `FirstArrayToLookup` does contains `Array1` and `Array2`, and the check condition for `FirstArrayToLookup` is `FirstStringContains`, and `FirstStringContains` also does contains `Array1` and `Array2` which should print the `First Array to Lookup`, but it doesn't

Comment: I think the problem might present itself easier if you manually write out what LINQ is doing behind the scenes. The `.All()` isn't doing what I think you think it's doing. The first loop is looping through your first List which contains two items. The first iteration of that loop is going to compare against `"FirstArray1"`, which does contain `"Array1"` but does NOT contain `"Array2"`. So that's going to immediately return false, thus invalidating the rest of the loop. Make sense? The `.All()` is against every entry, not just against any entry. Did you mean to use `.Any()` instead of `.All()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to **match the two sequences element by element** (e.g. check whether *the first element* in `FirstArrayToLookup` contains *the first element* in `FirstStringContains` and *the second element* in `FirstArrayToLookup` contains *the second element* in `FirstStringContains`; and so on), you can use [`Enumerable.Zip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0) to perform element-wise comparison.

For the `First*`-scenario, you could do:

```
var allMatch = FirstArrayToLookup
    .Zip(FirstStringContains,
        ( lookupValue, searchValue ) => lookupValue.Contains(searchValue))
    .All(isMatch => isMatch);
```

The element-wise comparison would then look as follows for the first element:

```
( "FirstArray1", "Array1" ) => "FirstArray1".Contains("Array1"))
```

and as follows for the second element:

```
( "FirstArray2", "Array2" ) => "FirstArray2".Contains("Array2"))
```

Seeing as both `.Contains()` will return `true`, the following `.All(isMatch => isMatch)` will also return `true`.

`.Zip()` will process the two sequences in parallel until the shortest (if any) sequence ends. Therefore, if either sequence is longer than the other (and by that, it is guaranteed that there's not a full element-by-element match), that needs to be addressed before using the `.Zip()` operation.

I would suggest to create a method, something like the following:

```csharp
private static bool IsElementWiseMatch(List<string> lookupValues, string[] searchValues)
{
    if (lookupValues.Count != searchValues.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    return lookupValues
        .Zip(searchValues,
            ( lookupValue, searchValue ) => lookupValue.Contains(searchValue))
        .All(isMatch => isMatch);
}
```

and call it for each sequence pair:

```csharp
if (IsElementWiseMatch(FirstArrayToLookup, FirstStringContains))
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Array to Lookup");
}
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TLC5Qw).